# Error 1603 during MSP Installation

Tags: windows-installer, advanced-installer, msi-patch

I have an error during updating our software by using an MSP file wrapped in an EXE file.
I have the following versions:
`1.5.1810.0008` and `1.5.1810.0010`

Version '0008' is fully installed by an MSI file wrapped into an EXE File (created by Advanced Installer) and the patch file is an MSP file wrapped into an EXE File, too.

During patch installation, I got the following error:

`"This package can only be run from a bootstrapper."`

It's a feature which was implemented by Advanced Installer in version 13.2 or something near. This feature will fire the error if you execute an MSI file even if there is an EXE file with resources next to it. So that you have to execute the EXE file and not the MSI file. But I execute the EXE file, so this is my bootstrapper and I only have *resources inside* EXE files.

Problem is, this error is not being logged in the log file. The error in the log file has `code 1603`. Which regards to missing permissions or anti-virus software. And yet, after deactivating my antivirus software and rechecking permissions (full access) I still experience the same error.

Can anyone help me ivestigating in the `code 1603` problem?

Comment: Patching is a weak spot of mine, but one issue I keep tripping on is the fact that for minor upgrade patches to work you need to use identical MSI file names in both the old and the new MSI. Perhaps just verify that this is the case so you can rule out this error source.

Comment: Note that the described version change is ignored by Windows Installer when examining products. You should change something in the first three fields if you want well-defined version orders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the product code. Because the product code was different, it didn't work, even if the error message was misleading.

> Product code has to be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Error 1603 in MSI-land is the most generic error and can mean just about anything. I would remove the variables from your upgrade and trying running the patch without the bootstapper (exe). Be sure the log the patch `/l*v <pathToLog>`. That log hopefully can provide more information.

I don't think this is your issue, but I would point out that Windows install will only recognize the first 3 octets in your version. You should probably change your versioning scheme to account for this. I can't find the proper MS link for this but I did find [this](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=484) on AdvancedInstallers forums.

Answer (score 0):

I think the way this is implemented is likely to be with a custom action (and not a launch condition) because of the 1603 error. The typical implementation has the bootstrapper set a property in the command line launch of the MSI file. The custom action fails the install if this property has the wrong value.

When you say "this my bootstrapper" does that mean that you created the exe that is installing the patch? If that is the case you have two options:

1. See if Advanced Installer will tell you how that check works so that you can set the property to the required value on the patch install command line, or...
2. Set verbose logging and repeat the original product install somewhere. If you are lucky you will see the property value in the log, and that will tell you what you need to set on the patch install command line. If it's obvious it may have a name that is obviously related to bootstrapping.